# Capybara: #drag_to not triggering ondragover event

Tags: rspec, cucumber, capybara

I can't get Capybara's `drag_to` event to mimic my app's behavior.

A simple version.

**Given the HTML**

```
<div id="target" ondragover="this.innerHTML = 'Dragged To Target!'">Target!</div>
<div id="source" draggable="true">Drag Me!</div>
```

**When I drag the source to the target using Selenium, Poltergeist, Rack Test, or Webkit**

```
source = Capybara.find('#source')
target = Capybara.find('#target')

source.drag_to(target)
```

**Then I should see the element has been dragged over**

```
expect(target.text).to eq('Dragged To Target!')
```

However, instead I get the following failed test:

```
expected: "Dragged To Target!"
got: "Target!"
```

This behavior works in real life. How can I test it with Capybara?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately selenium with firefox doesn't work with HTML 5 drag and drop - https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3604 - it's been an open issue for a long time

Comment: Thanks @tom. Looks like this fails for me with Poltergeist, Rack Test, and Webkit, too. It also fails if I register :chrome with Selenium. What does it work with?

Comment: I know it works with jQuery draggable since there's a test in capybara for that. Other than that I don't know what, if anything, works with HTML 5 drag and drop - maybe capybara-webkit - some browsers require you to set the data in ondragstart before dragging will actually happen

Comment: @Nakilon React is irrelevant to this -- the key is whether or not the drag and drop is implemented via HTML 5 drag and drop or via JS handlers watching for `mousedown`, `mousemove`, and `mouseup` events.  If it's the latter it should work, if it's the former it probably won't since no browser currently produces the HTML5 `dragstart`, `dragover`, etc events when used via webdriver - although you can try with the latest Capybara (3.7.0) and latest Chrome or FF 62+ since that does attempt to simulate the correct HTML5 events.